# How can a REGEX extract a pattern repeatedly?

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I want to extract a list of sections from an email that are listed in the format

`Section 26, 753, 87, 201, 47`

I know that this certain kind of formatting is present in my document but I have no idea where. How can I write a regex that will extract all of the section numbers? (Sorry, I'll post the pattern I already have later.) Currently, it looks for the section phrase, followed by a space, followed by a number. How are the rest extracted? Perhaps 0 or more repetitions of comma, space, number? How exactly is that formatted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly returning a variable number of captures from a regex is not possible with PHP/PCRE (although there are implementations that support this, notably [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures.aspx) and [Perl 6](http://feather.perl6.nl/syn/S05.html#Repeated_captures_of_the_same_subrule)).

With PHP, you have to write code.  There are a variety of options - remove matches from the string in a loop, extract the list and then use preg_match_all to get the numbers, and so on - but I think I would just extract the whole list into its own string and use `split` (well, `preg_split`) to get the individual section numbers:

```
$str = 'Section 26, 753, 87, 201, 47';
if (preg_match('/Section\s+(\d+(?:,\s*\d+)*)/', $str, $match)) {
  $sections = preg_split('/,\s*/', $match[1]);
}

print_r($sections);
```

Which gives the desired result:

```
 Array (
     [0] => 26
     [1] => 753
     [2] => 87
     [3] => 201
     [4] => 47 
)
```

Comment: Hmm, PHP is probably not the language that I want to use for this project then. I posted this question right before I came up with a different method for extracting data from my semi-structured document, and retrieving a variable number of captures from large sections of a very large document is exactly what I need. Are you aware is Python supports this functionality? Do you know of any reference that might list languages that do?